# Configure differerent names for git difftool labels (directory names) 'left' and 'right'?

Tags: git, git-difftool

Using `difftool` with `meld` works well, yet the headers meld shows for the two sides are 'left' and 'right'. For `git diff` itself there are the options `--src-prefix` and `--dst-prefix` to rename the 'a' and 'b' prefix, but it has no influence on `difftool`.

I am using the configuration

```
[difftool]
  prompt = false
[difftool "meld"]
  cmd = meld "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

and run

```
git difftool --dir-diff some-branch
```

Is there a way to get a branch name or at least a commit hash instead of the 'left' and 'right' labels?

Comment: Unfortunately `git difftool` does not (currently at least) have a way of communicating these to the tool. It builds a couple of temporary directories (named `<randomized-prefix>/left/` and `<randomized-prefix>/right/`) and invokes the tool with these two names available in `$LOCAL` and `$REMOTE`, which presumably is where meld is coming up with those names. These are hardcoded into `builtin/difftool.c`.

Comment: It would be relatively easy to allow user-specified strings instead of `left` and `right` here, or branch names, or hash IDs, or whatever, but you'll have to make this change yourself (and then submit it to the Git mailing list if you want it to be added to an official Git distribution). You might also consider having difftool set up some env variables that one can use in the `cmd =` setting as well.